# Information about current Moderators

Tags: discussion, election

To help inform voters on the up coming election, I would like to have more information about our current Moderators on RPG SE.

SevenSidedDie's question in [2017 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6914/30319) is what sparked this idea, as well as Lino Frank Ciaralli's nomination.

What knowledge, availability, skills, background, etc. do our current Mods have?

*This question is intended for SevenSidedDie & mxyzplk as it seems wax eagle is stepping down*

Comment: Yeah guys, show us your character sheets.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure how valuable this is. This election isn't really about us, and I'd be concerned this would become a distracting side-show. More selfishly, the kind of information that would satisfy this Q is time-consuming to write. [My original Questionnaire answers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5517) are still available too, though there's been some evolution since then.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie As a nominee, I'm interested to know at least if there's specific areas you feel diversity is lacking, so we can respond to those in a "yes, I can add to that" or "no, I can't add to that" sort of ways. If you feel this would be counterproductive I can respect that.

Comment: @doppelgreener I'm somewhat concerned it might be — like, too much of a shopping list. The beauty of the Questionnaire is that it brings out the candidate's own perspectives and interpretations of the questions and conditions around the questions. I wouldn't want to bend those perceptions by pre-filtering them through what *I* think the mod team needs.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Right, so, uninformed by what you think it needs, I could look at it and see what *I* think it needs and respond accordingly with how I'm adding to it -- and what I don't think it needs more of and where I might not be contributing in that regard.

Comment: @doppelgreener Yeah, that's the kind of thing that I think the community really appreciates seeing.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I didn't even think of it that way but yeah, I'm 100% with you. Honestly just a look at the original Nomination would be minimally sufficient, and the questionnaire the cherry on top. Thanks for this! My intention wasn't for shopping list, but something like. Candidate A seems to have the highest credentials, but Candidate B has x/y skill that even though doesn't make them the most qualified Mod, would make them sufficiently qualified as a mod, but add skill to Mod group as a whole

Comment: @JohnGrabanski - Also, there have been users on some SE sites that were highly active on their sites, fit the "shopping list" down to a T, and turned out to be outright disasters as moderators and been asked to step down. Conversely, less experienced moderators have handled the job brilliantly. It's like being a GM, some are brilliant, others...not so much.

Comment: I'd rather the election be about the candidates, not the sitting mods.

Comment: what @mxyzplk said.