# 2020 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

The 2020 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Related: [2020 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9873/2020-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) and [Questionnaire](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9926/2020-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire). Also, for reference, the previous elections: [2012](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/1), [2015](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/2), [2017](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/3), and [2019](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/4)

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and unfeature this since the election *event* shows in the sidebar and the questionnaire and resignations are also featured.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the 2020 election has concluded and this post is not soliciting answers.